# R Plot.ly scatterplot color error with many symbols

Tags: r, plotly

Here's an example of the issue that I see in R:

```
plot_ly(x=1:20,y=1:20,color=1:20,mode='markers')
```

correctly gives:

[image]

However with two different symbol types, the scatterplot reduces to 2 colors (the hover text retains the 20 colors)

```
plot_ly(x=1:20,y=1:20,color=1:20,mode='markers',symbol=c(rep(0,10),rep(1,10)))
```

giving:

[image]

I've tried manually editing the color palette, but this didn't help either. Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Maybe you could turn this into a dataframe and add another reference variable for symbol?

Comment: @Sumedh: Same issues with data frames. I'm assuming you mean:

df=data.frame(x=1:20,y=1:20,symbol=c(rep(0,10),rep(1,10)))
plot_ly(x=df$x,y=df$y,color=1:20,mode='markers',symbol=df$symbol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the colors in the `marker` argument for this.

```
plot_ly(x = 1:20, y = 1:20, mode = "markers", type = "scatter",
    marker = list(symbol = c(rep(1,10), rep(3,10)),
            color = colorRampPalette(c("green", "yellow", "red"))(20),
            size = 18  # helps see the color better for the example
    )
)
```